# jquery scroll to div and focus a textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to achieve two things with a single onclick of anchor tag. First, when I click on search, I am scrolling to a particular div, and then trying to focus on the textbox within that div. Below is the link to the sample code. I am able to scroll to the div, but somehow the textbox is losing focus. What is wrong with the code?

http://jsfiddle.net/e9tJ5/1/

Comment: Works for me - Chrome. :)  I assume you're on firefox: http://www.symphonious.net/2010/11/24/controlling-focus-in-firefox/

Comment: Another confirmation, working in Chrome.

Comment: Not working in Firefox (the focus bit)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevetDefault.

```
$("#searchlink").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#searchtext").focus();
});
```

Return false also does the same.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/e9tJ5/5/

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in all browsers tested except Firefox.  See here for more info: http://www.symphonious.net/2010/11/24/controlling-focus-in-firefox/

Answer (score 1):

I've added second `$("#searchtext").focus();` and it works in firefox. not elegant but works.

Answer (score 1):

```
      $("#searchlink").click(function(){
        $("#searchtext").focus();
        return false;
      });
```